# Background logo have to be seen using CSS

Tags: css

```css
#blue:hover,#green:hover,#Reset:hover
  {
  background: #00ff00;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00ff00, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
    
  
  }
  
  
  #blue{
   background: lightblue url(http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Application/Glassy%20Software/WLM.png) no-repeat 10px center;
   height: 32px;
   padding-left: 36px;
    background-size:contain;
   <!---webkit-border-radius: 25;
   -moz-border-radius: 25;!-->
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: blue;
   font-size: 15px;
   border: solid black 2px;
   text-decoration: none;
   }
   
  #green{
   background: lightgreen url(http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Application/Glassy%20Software/WLM.png) no-repeat 5px center;
    background-size:contain;
   height: 32px;
   padding-left: 36px;
   <!--webkit-border-radius: 20;
   -moz-border-radius: 20; !-->
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: blue;
   font-size: 15px;
   border: solid black 2px;
   text-decoration: none;
   
   
   }
   #Reset{
   background: orange url(http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Application/Glassy%20Software/WLM.png) no-repeat 5px center;
    background-size:contain;
   height: 32px;
   padding-left: 50px;
   <!---webkit-border-radius: 20;
   -moz-border-radius: 20;!-->
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: black;
   font-size: 15px;
   border: solid black 2px;
   text-decoration: none;
   
   }
```

```html
<div class= "buttons">
 <button class="btnExample" id="Reset" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Reset()"/>ALL</button>
 <button class="btnExample" id="blue" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1()"/>Button1</button>
 <button class="btnExample" id="blue" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1"/>Button1</button>
 <button class="btnExample" id="blue" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1"/>Button1</button>
 <!--<button class="btnExample" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="SWSDCuPf()"/>SW SD CuPf</button>-->
 <button class="btnExample" id="blue" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1"/>Button1</button>
 <!--<button class="btnExample" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="qchamp()"/>Q-Champ</button>-->
 <button class="btnExample" id="green" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1"/>Button1</button>
 <button class="btnExample" id="green" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1"/>Button1</button>
 <button class="btnExample" id="green" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Button1"/>Button1</button>
```

The main problem on Hover I could not see my image in button . Nothing has to be changed in Html I need only in CSS part has to be changed . Is there any way to do that by using CSS3. 
The image is a Logo at first its showing there is no problem with that but when I hover the logo is hide.

Comment: you do not declare a background image with a logo for the hover but some other "image" (gradient)... so that's why you cannot see it.

Comment: So I have add the same link to hover also is it?

Comment: As I can see u want gradient as well image on hover right ?

Comment: Ya exactly. I would like to have both.

Comment: Use a pseudo element to place the person image over the link.

Comment: @marczking why I am using logo inside a button is because its company standard . Th e above use just a example that I was going to show.

Comment: @ZachSaucier could you please use my example and give a try because i looked into it but there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use multiple same `id`, it's invalid markup, use `class` instead.

And for your question, you can use different approaches, here is one using a pseudo class.
Your Logo is placed in there, so when you change the background of your `button` the logo is not affected / overwriten :)

```css
button {
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    background-size: contain;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: inherit;
    width: 50px;
    background: url(http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Application/Glassy%20Software/WLM.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
}
button:hover {
    background: #00ff00;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00, #3498db);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00ff00, #3498db);
}
```

```html
<button>I am a button</button>
```

Also you might want to read into CSS a little more ;)

Comment: Thank you giving an idea . Actually that is just an example . In my project the button have to be in those colour only . its some colour code . so that's why I have to use as ID .